# Load image after click on dropdownlist (Yii2)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I'm trying to display an image on the same page when clicking on the dropdown list. But I don't know how to apply it using yii2. Can anyone help me?

The ideas like this:

Name : [here is dropdown]

Image : [image is displayed automatically after clicking the dropdown list above]

Comment: Use javascript / jquery to change the image by triggering onchange event of the dropdown.

Comment: Yeah i know but how to implement it using Yii2?

Comment: As @ViswanathPolaki said, write your js code in seperate js file and include that js file OR register you js in view file. [Click this link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-client-scripts) for detailed info.

Comment: create a form with the select list in one of your url's (action). then send your images to the view with unique ids / classes (one to one mapping with select options). Use script tag / include js file on the view and then write your code

Comment: oh i seeeee. okay thank you ^^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no attempt made to solve the problem